# How do I view the contents of a set in Javascript in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, set

I am using Visual Studio Code Insiders.
I am teaching myself this as well as Javascript at the same time using a textbook from SitePoint.

I noticed that when I tried to display the contents of my set as shown in the book, I could only display the number of elements in the set. However, I was supposed to see the contents of the set. When using the command line, the contents did indeed show.

Is it my text editor settings, or is this normal? What can I do to be able to see the contents of my sets on my text editor? Am I supposed to keep copying and pasting my sets into the command line to see if they work?

This is what I entered:

```
const letters = new Set ('hello');
console.log(letters);
```

This is what VS Code Insider printed:

```
>>Set(4) {}
```

This is what the command line printed:

```
const letters = new Set('hello');
>>undefined

console.log(letters);
>>Set { 'h', 'e', 'l', 'o' }
```

I find I have no problem printing the contents of an array, so I'm not sure what's wrong.

Comment: How are you printing in VSCode ? Through an integrated terminal ? And which executable is used, Node of something else ?

Comment: You could use `Array.from(letters)` if you want to see it the same way as an array

Comment: @Seblor, It is an integrated terminal, but I am not sure which executable is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I noticed that when I tried to display the contents of my set as shown in the book, I could only display the number of elements in the set

Displaying the contents of a variable in JavaScript depends on the environment in which JavaScript runs.

As you pointed out, VS Code displays differently than the command line. Each of them are different interpreters.

> is this normal?

Yes

> What can I do to be able to see the contents of my sets on my text editor? [...] I find I have no problem printing the contents of an array

Since it works for an array (which indicates that both interpreters have very similar implementation for this type) you can convert the `Set` into an array when displaying:

```js
const letters = new Set ('hello');
console.log(Array.from(letters));
console.log([...letters]) // or this way
```